# Suppress warning for rsOverlappingReportItems

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, reportviewer

Is there a way to suppress the following warning?

> warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The
>   image 'image3' and the image 'image1'
>   overlap. Overlapping report items are
>   not supported in all renderers.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem. In the MSDN documentation, it says that you should be able to enter a warning identifier in the Suppress warnings textbox, but I cant find any warning identifier.

Comment: There does not seem to be a solution for this problem: http://forums.asp.net/p/1314684/2599937.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, I think the answer is indeed "No" - at least for the 2008 products.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "real solution" for VS2010 either. I have found that dropping the projects warning level (RightClickOnTheProject ~ Properties Project ~ Build ~ Warning Level = 0 or 1) supresses this warning, but I don't want to risk that, because I don't know what else that supresses, so I'll just have to put up with losing my warnings in the blizard. Sigh.

Comment: Is there a solution for VS2019?

Answer (score 7):

So,

This is an old question, but one that I've been meaning to look at for a while.  After some digging, it turns out that you need to use 'rsOverlappingReportItems' as the warning number, and then it works.

Update : This is found under the "Build" tab of project properties.  I've noticed some people mention rptproj files.  Not quite sure what kind of project that is.  The below is for standard libraries (.dll) (.csproj), where an RDLC file is included.

[image]

Comment: Where do you go to set this?  Solution properties, project properties or Visual Studio Options?

Comment: I would love to give this a +1, but like Dave Slinn, I would need to know where this is.  I'm using VS 2019/2022 and can't find that where I would expect it (properties of rdl, properties of rptproj).

Comment: Just checked to see if that could be manually added to the rptproj file using NoWarn, and that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error started showing up completely out of the blue - and only on 1 particular RDLC, even though we had 4 RDLC's with almost identical layouts. Previously all 4 layouts had worked absolutely fine.

I noticed in the error list a different error for the RDLC, and when I solved that, all the "Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers" errors suddenly disappeared after a solution rebuild.

The additional error was:

> An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native
> compiler return value: ‘[BC30179] class 'textbox12_TextBoxExprHost'
> and class 'Textbox12_TextBoxExprHost' conflict in class
> 'ReportExprHostImpl'.’

The fix for this was to find my controls "Textbox12" and "textbox12" and give them better names that did not conflict with each other. After the Solution Rebuild all the errors on the RDLC disappeared.

(Visual Studio 2019 / .NET 4.8 target)