# Suppress rsOverlappingReportItems warning in RDLC files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to suppress such warnings? It could be either for a single file or for the whole project.

The message comes out like this:

```
Warning X   The text box ‘’ and the text box ‘’ overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117874/suppress-warning-for-rsoverlappingreportitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the *Positions (**Top, Left**)* and *Sizes (**Width, Height**)* properties and adjust those properties to fix this warnings.

**Example:**

```
Textbox1 => Left = 1in, Width = 2in
Textbox2 => Left = 2.8in, Width = 5in  //overlapping
```

**Fix:**

```
Textbox2 => Left = Textbox1.Left + Textbox1.Width + <Small Space>
Textbox2 => Left = 1in           + 2in            + 0.00200in     //Fix
```

I did it and the build warnings gone. This may be useful.