# Ignore Reporting-Services Warnings in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm trying to get rid of the 'rsOverlappingReportItems'-Warnings in the Visual Studio, since we did the overlapping on purpose.

I did the usual proceeding by getting the warning-code:

> SomeRDLC.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: The text box
>   ‘textbox236’ and the text box ‘textbox43’ overlap. Overlapping report
>   items are not supported in all renderers.

In this case, I just expected "rsOverlappingReportItems" to be the Code.
Then I added it on the Project under Build --> Support Warnings.

But this doesn't seem to work this way. As far as I've seen, there is no way to tell the Reporting-Services explictly to ignore this warning, but shouldn't it possible to tell that to the Compiler?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress warning for rsOverlappingReportItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117874/suppress-warning-for-rsoverlappingreportitems)